# ASP.NET Put MVC Application in a subdirectory

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, shared-hosting

So I've bought a shared hosting and I want to put a separate asp.net mvc application in a subdirectory. In the root directory it has a normal asp.net application.

However when I upload the whole MVC project to the subdirectory I'm getting an configuration error:

The code subdirectory '/mobile/App_Code/CSCode/' does not exist.

What can I do to make this working?

Thanks alot already!

Comment: Create that directory?

Comment: When you add an application to a sub-domain the application still works as though it is the root. You don't need to reference from the top down so you should be able to remove /mobile. Sub-domains are their own sites, the only difference is the way you hit it through the url. Instead of www.yoursite.com it would be mobile.yoursite.com

Comment: I tried to acces: mobile.example.com, it still uses the webconfig from the root directory.

Comment: When you added the site in your shared hosting did you just add a folder or did you add a sub-domain?

Comment: I added a subdomain through their panel, and I redirected that subdomain to my 'mobile' folder in the webconfig.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar scenario where i have GoDaddy shared hosting account. To make sure your MVC application work under ASP.Net sub-directory you have to take care of following points

- Make sure you created your sub-directory by adding it as web
  application/ web site from hosting control panel.
- If you have any Begin or End request logic written in Global.ascx of
  parent ASP.Net website. Please modified it, to make sure it will by
  pass for this sub site. In the case of subsite always parent site
  Global.ascx logic fired first.
- If needed Web.config of parent site should be reconfigured to support
  sub-site
- Sometime shared hosting provider not have MVC component that you are
  using in their server GAC. So you have to keep it in your bin folder